# Failure triggering a GitHub action from Dockerized Python/Flask app

Tags: python, docker, github, flask, github-actions

So I have this Flask application that triggers GitHub actions and it works fine locally and also when it's run on a VM somewhere in the cloud.

The issue I am having is when I try to dockerize the app it fails to authorize the requests with the following message:

```
:{'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application / vnd.github.everest - preview + json', 'Authorization': 'token ghp_*****'}
:b'{"message":"Bad credentials","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest"}'
:401
https://api.github.com/repos/<myname>/<myproject>/dispatches
```

Here's the code I am using the send out the requests:

```
GITHUB_ACTION_TOKEN = os.getenv('ACTION_TOKEN')
GITHUB_ACTIONS_API_URL = 'https://api.github.com/repos/<myname>/<myproject>/dispatches'
r = requests.post(GITHUB_ACTIONS_API_URL, headers=GITHUB_ACTION_REQUEST_HEADER, json=json_data)
```

Is there any issue authorizing HTTPS requests from a dockerized app with GitHub actions?

When I bashed into the Docker container and tried the following it surprisingly worked:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Accept: application / vnd.github.everest - preview + json' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Authorization: token ghp_******' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Content-Length: 332' -H 'Content-type: application/json' -H 'User-Agent: python-requests/2.27.1' -d '{"event_type": "build-trigger", "client_payload": {"some_param": "some-value"}}' https://api.github.com/repos/<myname>/<myproject>/dispatches
```

Any idea someone?

Comment: maybe use `print()` to see what you have in all variables in `requests.post`

Comment: I solved this issue with just sending a CURL request using subprocess.run()...

Comment: there is page [curl converter](https://curlconverter.com/) which can convert curl command to different languages - and it can convert also to Python `requests` (but sometimes it may need correction). You may also `curl` and `request` with url` `https://httpbin.org/post`  and it will send back all headers and other information and you can check if python sends the same data as curl. Other method is to use local proxy server like [Charlie](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) to see all data in requests from `curl` and `python` and compare them.